# Editing table row using jquery

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I want to add edit capability to rows selected in a table, saving results to localStorage.

I want to enable users to either edit inline or to re-populate form fields where user can then edit. Either would be great.

I am entirely new to programming so certain my lack of knowledge is what's holding me back from understanding how to implement solution in light of my code.

```html
<table id="sprintTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Select</th>
      <th>Sprint Name</th>
      <th>Dev Phase</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="record"></td>
      <td>Introduction to Developing</td>
      <td>Committed</td>
      <td>July 17</td>
      <td style="background-color:rgb(5, 122, 15);color:rgb(5, 122, 15);">Status</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="sprintEditButtons">
  <button type="button" id="delete-sprint" class="action-button">Delete Sprint</button>
  <button type="button" id="edit-sprint" class="action-button">Edit Sprint</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the code you have tried so far

Comment: This isn't a free write-my-code or do-my-research service. We will help you with a task you have tried to solve yourself, where you have encountered a specific issue. If you are new to programming and have no idea how to approach the requirement then the best thing to do would be to study tutorials etc about your chosen technologies until you have sufficient understanding to have some idea how you might start. If we just write you an answer, then there is a good chance you might not understand it anyway, so you wouldn't really learn much.

Comment: As a general hint, you first need to learn how to handle user input events (e.g. detecting a button click and then running some code in a function as a result). Then you need to understand how to add and replace elements from the DOM (i.e. the object model representing your HTML page), so that you can insert the necessary form fields. (Or you could possibly look into the [HTML5 contenteditable feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) and see if that would suit your scenario).

Comment: Then lastly you need to understand how to read the input given by the user, collate it into an object and then how to save it into localstorage. All of that is too broad for one single answer on StackOverflow. But you can research each of the stages I've mentioned, get each bit working and gradually work towards the completed solution. If you get stuck with a specific part of the code on the way, that would be a much more suitable topic for a question here. Thanks.

Comment: understood. i tried to load my jquery but it wasn't being accepted. I've been struggling or trying for several days. Thank you for the mentoring. Appreciate it very much

Comment: Thank you so much, AD. Sometimes just getting structure, focus for how to tackle is HUGELY helpful. Much thanks! And thnx for coaching on how to be better user here too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Data added on table when click on submit.

var edit_row = null;

$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    var fname = $("#fname").val();
    var lname = $("#lname").val();
    var number = $("#number").val();
    var row = "<tr><td class='first'>" +
        fname +
        "</td><td class='last'>" +
        lname +
        "</td><td class='mobile'>" +
        number +
        '</td><td><a href="" class="fas fa-edit edit text-primary" style="cursor:pointer"></a> <a class="fas fa-trash-alt dlt text-danger" style="cursor:pointer"></a></td></tr>';

    if (edit_row) {
        $("#myTable tbody").find($(edit_row)).replaceWith(row);
        edit_row = null;
    }
    else if ((fname != "" && lname != "" && number != "")) {
        $("#myTable tbody").append(row);
    }

// After submit all values are null using below codes.

    $("#fname").val('');
    $("#lname").val('');
    $("#number").val('');
});

// Data delete in table when click on delete button.

$(document).on('click', '.dlt', function () {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    return false;
});

// Data again fill in form when click on edit.
    
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function () {
    edit_row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $("#fname").val($(this).closest('tr').find('.first').text());
    $("#lname").val($(this).closest('tr').find('.last').text());
    $("#number").val($(this).closest('tr').find('.mobile').text());
});


// Thank you.
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image"
        href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoqksPBDeWpznZfj0_XtgkNO5npIUwP7n7n0GCXos3PGoEGHLwapvcf_qlnbXWf-bd-Us&usqp=CAU">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        .form-label {
            margin: 0%;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Edit and Delete</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- form -->

    <div class="container mt-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form class="row" id="myForm">
            <div class="col-8">
                <label for="fname" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 mt-3">
                <label for="lname" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-8 mt-3">
                <label for="number" class="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                <input type="tel" class="form-control" maxlength="10" minlength="10" id="number"
                    placeholder="Mobile Number">
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Table -->

    <table class="table container mt-5" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Mobile Number</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <footer style="float: right;display: block;position: fixed;bottom: 20px;right: 20px;">Made by <a style="text-decoration: none;color: black;font-weight: 600;" href="https://www.instagram.com/_ridham_golakiya/">Ridham Golakiya</a></footer>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta2/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="edit&delete.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```